# Laravel - Calling shortcodes stored in database

Tags: php, laravel

I am building a CMS in Laravel where most of the content is being managed via [Trumbowyg](https://alex-d.github.io/Trumbowyg/)'s wysiwyg editor and in addition I installed a [Laravel Shortcodes plugin](https://vedmant.com/laravel-shortcodes/) which lets me easily generate shortcodes and register them via the `AppServiceProvider`.

Now everything works smoothly and seems like the shortcodes are being properly registered, but the problem is that once the shortcodes are being retrieved from the DB - they are not being rendered on the blade template itself, even though the compiled string looks ok.

the `Post`'s `content` field in the DB holds this data -

```
<div>
  <p>Testing</p>
  {{ Shortcodes::render('[test]') }}
</div>
```

The shortcode itself is registered in AppServicePorvider `boot()` method like this -

```
Shortcodes::add('test', function ($atts, $content, $tag, $manager) {
            return new HtmlString('<strong>some test shortcode</strong>');
        });
```

Now, in my ViewsController, I retrieve and compile the template like this -

```
$post = Post::find(1);
        $desc = Blade::compileString($post->content);
```

When I `dd($desc)`, I'm indeed getting -

```
<p>Testing</p>
<?php
echo e(Shortcodes::render('[test]'));
?>
```

But when I try to `{!! $content !!}` within the blade template I only see the `<p>Testing</p>` part and the shortcode is simply eliminated from the view itself, like it totally ignores it.

*-Yes, I know that serving php code straight out of the database is considered a bad security practice, but I simply couldn't find a more creative approach for this problem*

Comment: echoing that string won't execute any code, you are just echoing a string ... to execute that as PHP you would be using `eval` and that is a major not good thing to do  ... Blade isn't meant for this purpose

Comment: Thanks. 
So how would you approach this problem?.. I guess im not the first one who's building a CMS with an options for shortcodes